# Case Date Filter in Where Clause - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to return a date range dependent on current_date. The logic is as follows:

If the current month is January then return the beginning of the prior year; otherwise return the beginning of the current year.

The attached code keeps throwing a syntax error. I'm using a NS 64bit ODBC in Alteryx to pull the info.

Code :

```
and t.TRANDATE between

        --period beg
        (case
            when to_char(current_date, 'MM')='01' then add_months(trunc(current_date, 'YYYY'),-12)
            else trunc(current_date, 'YYYY')
        end)
    and
        --period end
        trunc(current_date,'MM')-1/84600)
```

Any suggestions on how to clear the syntax error or restructure the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
AND t.TRANDATE >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(current_date, -1), 'YYYY')
AND t.TRANDATE <  TRUNC(current_date,'MM')
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error? *Which* syntax error? I don't get any:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dual
  3  where sysdate not between
  4    case when to_char(current_date, 'mm') = '01' then add_months(trunc(current_date, 'YYYY'),-12)
  5         else trunc(current_date, 'yyyy')
  6    end
  7    and trunc(current_date, 'mm') - 1/84600;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

(I used `NOT BETWEEN` and the `DUAL` table as I don't have your table(s), just to show that this code works OK).